# Python Geo Scrape Using Tweepy

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary, tweepy

I am working with Twitter's API and `tweepy` in the hopes of scraping available geolocation coordinates from Tweets. My end goal is to store only the coordinates of each Tweet in a table.

My issue is that when location Tweets, I run into an error where more information than the coordinates is provided:

[image: earlier attempt]

My code thus far is as follows:

---

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import tweepy
import csv

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        if status.retweeted:
            return

        if True:

            coords = status.coordinates
            geo = status.geo

        if geo is not None:
            geo = json.dumps(geo)

        if coords is not None:
            coords = json.dumps(coords)    

            print(coords, geo)
            with open('coordinates_data.csv', 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow([coords,geo])


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_error disconnects the stream
            return False

LOCATIONS = [-124.7771694, 24.520833, -66.947028, 49.384472,        # Contiguous US
                 -164.639405, 58.806859, -144.152365, 71.76871,         # Alaska
                 -160.161542, 18.776344, -154.641396, 22.878623]        # Hawaii

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('access auths', 'access auths')
auth.set_access_token('token','token')

api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.me()

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)  
myStream.filter(locations=LOCATIONS)
```

---

I'm sure this issue relates to my lack of 'json' understanding, or that I need to use a data dictionary.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! this looks like homework! please see [asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6619250) first
and [edit] your question if required.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, Tweepy is a third-party library that interfaces with Twitter's API.

That's just how Twitter represents [coordinates objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/geo-objects#coordinates). Tweepy parses the `coordinates` attribute of the `Status`/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) data as the dictionary that it is. You can simply access the `coordinates` field as a key for that dictionary to get the list with the longitude and latitude values.

You also have a missing quotation mark, `'`, where you initialize `auth`, but I assume that's a typo from when you replaced your credentials for this question.